# Swift - prepareForSegue called but view controller not showing

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have two `ViewControllers`. One for login and one for next page. The login in done in my server. Once the user enter the correct username and password it will segue to the next page. It worked for me. First time user had to enter username and password. After one successful attempt I save the username and password in `UserDefaults` and use that to login automatically. This method worked for me. After sometime I don't know what happened the next page not showing after login. I checked `prepareForSegue` and it's getting called and I printed the segue identifier. All are correct. But the next view controller not showing. I used the following code in `viewDidAppear` to login automatically.

```
if pref.string(forKey: "username") != nil && pref.string(forKey: "password") != nil {
        let user = self.pref.string(forKey: "username")
        let pass = self.pref.string(forKey: "password")
        self.eUser.text = user
        self.ePass.text = pass
        login_account()
    }
```

After successful login I'm using following code to `performSegue`

```
if response == "Invalid credentials" {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.stopAnimating()
            self.show_alert(response)
        })
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.stopAnimating()
            self.saveCredentials(username: user, password: pass)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "test_segue", sender: self)
        })
    }
```

Sometimes segue working and sometimes not working.

When this occurs the buttons and textfields on login page is not touchable.

Comment: did you have embedded navigation controller  ?

Comment: Yes. The segue is presenting NavigationController

Comment: can you show your storyboard scene ,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sorry the segue did goes to second view controller. It is blocked by a function for creating random number. solved it thanks.

Comment: good, welcome bro.....